# Get Longitude and Latitude using JavaScript and set these to vars

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Today is my first day using the Google Maps API. Now I have a DIV with an id of "map" the following code...

```
function initializeMap() {

        var opts = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0), // ignore the zero values for now
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), opts);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}
```

and I call this using `window.onload = initializeMap`

Okay I'd like to center the map in my current location. I know I can get the long and lat using

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);

function displayLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
 }
```

Now I'm a little lost with how the position object is pushed back to success handler displayLocation. Anyway how can I pass the latitude & longitude to the initializeMap() function like so...

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng( latitude, longitude)
```

I'm currently looking at the Google Maps API docs as I'm sure there's a method to get this but I'd like to use the latitude, longitude in different functions so I guess I'm asking how can I make these variables accessible to all functions (like a global but not a bad global) instead of being only available to the `displayLocation` function . Sorry if this is worded poorly... if I'm confusing people please say and I'll reword this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just declare

```
var latitude, longitude;
```

into a parent scope, so the function is

```
function displayLocation(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude; /* no var keyword */
    longitude = position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

of course the choice of the scope in which you should define those variables is up to you. Also, be aware that they will be `undefined` until `displayLocation` is not called

Comment: Cheers, what I've done is  window.onload = function(){navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);} then call the initializeMap() within the displayLocation() function, cheers